# Why does this loop execute only once?

Tags: php, loops

I found such php code :

```
$a = 5;
$i  = 4;
for($i = &$a; $i < 10; ++$i);

echo "a=$a, i=$i";
```

I would expect this loop to be executed 4 times since $i becomes a reference to a$(right?). However loop is executed only once and outputs :

a=10, i=10

I can't figure outh why it works like this. Any ideas?

Comment: There's a semicolon after your `for`. This is why curly brackets should always be required.

Comment: Correct indentation would basically SHOUT what the error is

Comment: its a good way of using up CPU cycles though

Comment: `$i = &$a;` ??? Why the `&` reference character

Comment: Science damn it. I didn't notice that semicolon.... This was a tricky question in quiz...:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works because the for statement is being processed like a single line statement as a result of the semicolon.

```
for($i = &$a; $i < 10; ++$i);
```

can also be seen as

```
for($i = &$a; $i < 10; ++$i) echo $i;
```

Without the curly brackets, the following line will be considered part of the for statement, your line being just a semicolon to indicate the end of the line.

The proper code would look like this.

```
$a = 5;
for($i = $a; $i < 10; ++$i) echo "a=$a, i=$i";
```